# How can I quote a numbered list in markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

I came across a question asking for comment on a list of items. The question was something like this:

> Are the following statements true?
>
> 1. The sky is blue
> 2. The earth is round
> 3. Aliens built the pyramids

In my answer, I wanted to include the list and answer each point in turn. Something like:

> 1. The sky is blue

blah blah blah, more blah blah, and some more blah blah.

> 2. The earth is round (this should be "**2**. The earth is round")

As you can see, the quoted `2.` is changed to `1.` by markdown. I cannot figure out how I can include the numbers from the original list in the quoted list, without markdown treating each entry as a *new* list and numbering from one.

I know I could use `2)` instead of `2.` but that is no longer, strictly speaking, a quote.

So, is there a way to quote a numbered list without having markup treat it as a list?

---

NOTE: I am not linking to the question because it is from the biology beta site. I am asking here because this meta is much more active and I have a better chance of an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make a standalone quote starting with a "2.", use the following:

```
> 2\. The earth is round
```

Turns into:

> 2. The earth is round

A literal `2.` turned into `1.` when standing alone is by design, since in Markdown you could write numbered lists as sequences of `1.`, `1.`, and so on.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I understood why it was happening, and it is normally a great feature, just couldn't get around it.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest I can get based on how you were trying it is this:

1. > The sky is blue

   General content here
2. > The earth is round

   More response
3. > Aliens built the pyramids

   Final Response

You can do this by moving the > to after the number, then use a space before your responses.

Comment: Yeah, I had tried that but I wanted the numbers to be part of the list. Slhck's answer is just what I needed. Thanks though :).